# How I can test uploading files into `input[type="file"]` Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js

I've wrote a custom `input[type="file"]` component.
And I'd like to write a unit test for the next situation:

1. Upload file to input
2. Read the file's name and write him to the tag span or another.

I wrote below test. But I think this is a wrong way to mock file in input.

```html
it("check download file to input", () => {
  const files = [
    {
      name: "test.png",
      size: 50000,
      type: "image/png"
    }
  ];
  const wrapper = mount(InputCropper);
  const input = wrapper.find('input[type="file"]');
  input.files = files;
  input.trigger("change");

  expect(input.files.length).to.equal(1);
});
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?